# In JUnit 5 test, how can I test a number whether it is positve or negative or a mix of both?

Tags: java, junit5

I'm new to JUnit testing. I've tried using conditions, but it doesn't seem to work using assertEquals. For example, assertEquals(1 > 0, 10) which gives me a failed test. Is there another way of doing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *assertTrue*, in your case: assertTrue(x > 0).

You can find all provided assertion-types [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html).